# selenium automation Mobile site: wait for hidden element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I've got a problem with hidden elements. The site is fully loaded so every items available, nothing to load, switch page.
I tried every options with ExpectedConditions but still not waited for the elements. With Find function I get the location, but the x,y coordinates are: (-125, 156) so it is not possible to click it (not visible also on the screen) 
Very bad workaround would be that while + Thread.Sleep(1000); and a counter..while x>0 and >0 
Which I want to avoid.. Any ideas? 
[image]
Example from the code:

```
    ChromeOptions chromeCapabilities = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeCapabilities.EnableMobileEmulation("iPhone 7");

    IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
    webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://m.exmaple.org");

    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0));

    IWebElement menu_1;
    IWebElement switch_left;

    switch_left = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("item_1"));
    switch_left.Click(); // ~3-5 sec while switched left because of animations


    driverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("item_1"))));
    menu_1 = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("item_1"));
    menu_1.Click(); System.InvalidOperationException: 'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (-125, 156)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If an element is not visible, you won't be able to click it. Are you sure you're not wanting to click something else? That possibly contains the invisible element?

Comment: So the steps:
Load page
Click switch_left (less than 500ms)
Click menu_1 and there.. I got the error...  because there is az animation.. than I can see the menu_1. 
So there I need the wait...

Comment: If I were you, I would probably look closely at the elements in the dom to see if there is any attribute on them to indicate the animation has happened, or the state of the visible page is left or right or whatever. If there is no such thing, then I would look up how to create a custom wait to wait until the element has stopped moving so you know the animation is done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are attempting to click an element when it is outside of the browser frame. You need a way to wait for the element to move into frame after a click. There is no built in method to do this so you will need a custom wait.

You should be able to use something like the below. It's basically waiting until the X/Y coordinates of the element (technically the top left corner) are within the browser frame. I think this will work for you.

```
public IWebElement WaitForElementToBeOnscreen(By locator)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until<IWebElement>(d =>
    {
        IWebElement element = d.FindElement(locator);
        if (element.Location.X > 0 &&
            element.Location.X < Driver.Manage().Window.Size.Width &&
            element.Location.Y > 0 &&
            element.Location.Y < Driver.Manage().Window.Size.Height)
        {
            return element;
        }

        return null;
    });

    return null;
}
```

NOTE: To make this even more accurate, you could take into account the size of the element. For example, make sure the X is greater than 0 and less than the window width - width of element... and so on.

Another issue you might run into is if the element never moves... it stays outside of the browser frame. If that happens, the wait will timeout. I'm not sure what you want to do in that case... you could wrap it in a `try-catch` and return `null` or whatever else you decide.